# Servlet-JSP URL Mapping communications

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i got a problem while i trying to send an action from.jsp to serlvet, when i push on the link i would to send action to servlet to handle it, but i got always 404 code error.

The class are divided like follow:

```
 Application    
           src
               servlets
                        controllerServlet.java
           WebContent
                     jsp
                         home.jsp
```

The code i wrote on the do get servlet method is:

```
{

    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    switch (action) {

    case "action1":
        System.out.println("action 1");
        break;
    }

}
```

And the code in jsp to recall the servlet is:

```
<li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controllerServlet?action=action1">Page1</a></li>
```

The web.xml file is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.1">
 <display-name>Application</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>/jsp/home.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
<servlet-name>controllerServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>servlets.controllerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>controllerServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/controllerServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

But i don't understand why don't work, anyone could help me?

Comment: Can you paste `web.xml`?

Comment: Don't see servlet mapping in `web.xml`? Can you add `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name> controllerServlet </servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/controllerServlet </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>` and try?

Comment: okay.. adding you a log statement for you. Do a `System.out.println("here");` in `controllerServlet`'s constructor then add `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` to your `<servlet>` tag and start/restart your webapp. Let me know if log "here" is printed